# Anaconda - Manually adding a built package

Tags: opencv, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I have build OpenCV (using cmake) and I can see the libs, include and bin files copied to my conda desired env. However, using `conda list` doesn't list the `OpenCV`. Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conda list` will only show `pip install` or `conda install` installed packages.

To verify if OpenCV works, type below to check the version.

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: I got your point. However, I try, from the terminal, to enter python, and try to import cv2 or cv and both fails! 

Your reply answers my question anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: If you are using OpenCV 3.x, should use `import cv2`.  The instruction on installing self-built in this [webpage](https://github.com/CCM2016/opencv-3.2.0_binary) might help if you are using Anaconda on Windows, no matter Python 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: @Kasparov92, above comment for you.

Comment: I am using anaconda on ubuntu, I build opencv using `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/conda_env` and I can see  the opencv files in the include, bin and lib folders of that env but when I have that env activated, I cannot import cv2! (I built opencv3.2)

Comment: Did you find `cv2.so` in your `~\{anaconda root}\envs\{env name}\Lib\site-packages` directory? If not, copy it to directory and try the import again. The exact path depends on how you set the anaconda install path, the env subpath should look like `~\{env name}\Lib\site-packages`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find cv2.so in that path so I remade the cmake step, I used the release version `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/anaconda/env/ ..` and after the `make install -j7` I could find the cv2.so in the path and the import and printing version succeeds

Comment: Is there a way to hack conda so that `conda list` shows the manually built and added packages, i.e. adding a file or editing a file somewhere?